# Adding multiple Managed Metadata columns to my enterprise wiki

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, page-layout, site-template

i have created a new enterprise wiki site collection, and i added many site columns of type Managed Metadata. then i link the new managed meta data columns to different term sets inside my term store.

but currently when i add/edit/read a wiki page i can not see the new columns . so is there a way to add the new Managed Metadata site columns to the following views:-

1. Add wiki page.
2. Edit a wiki page.
3. Read a wiki page.